# The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.?

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04

I have an online Ubuntu VPS (with Plesk already installed), I tried a very simple index.php script in the /var/www/html directory using the IP address of the server in the browser ex. 123.123.123.133/index.php, but the response was always (The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.)

the script was:

```
<?php
 phpinfo();
?>
```

I restarted apache2 many times and  I tried many of the solutions in the stack overflow but none of them worked for me.

any help with this issue??

Comment: Go to your apache.conf  (/etc/apache2/) and check if the docroot is correctly set.
Same for all vhost enable (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the directory where Plesk serves its files from. Is that really `/var/www/html`? I thought Plesk was using `/var/www/vhosts/<domain_name>`.

[Plesk documentation](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/administrator-guide/web-hosting/website-directory-structure.68695/)

Comment: in /var/www there are 2 folders, the html, and the vhosts, I uploaded the PHP file to each one of them but the same response

Comment: You should look for another folder below the vhosts folder that serves the files for host 123.123.123.133 or whatever hostname/IP you're using to access the web server.